# Can I have gradle cache dependencies w/out building a specific project

Tags: gradle

I regularly reformat my entire machine, wiping Gradle's dependency cache in the process. As part of my re-setup script I want Gradle to repopulate the dependency cache. Is there a way to tell Gradle to download and cache a dependency *without* having to build the project which depends on that dependency?

I suppose I could just have a dummy project that lists a bunch of dependencies and then build that project once in my script. But that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: I assume this is for personal projects, rather than projects that publish a build cache to something like artifactory, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle does not have a built-in task to cache a dependency, which is in fact a set of files: metadata, JAR and potentially more. In addition, for resolution, the origin repository matters.

An alternative option could be to backup and [restore the Gradle dependency cache](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:cache_copy).